# How to open app when input url of this app on Google Chorme?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I'm coding about open app when input **url** of app on Google Chrome.

[uri-scheme](https://xamarinhelp.com/uri-scheme/)

But I can't open my app when I input **url** on Google Chrome.

This is my code:

```
        <activity android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize" android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher" android:label="MobileApp" android:launchMode="singleInstance" android:theme="@style/MobileApp" android:windowSoftInputMode="stateUnspecified|adjustPan" android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <data android:scheme="mobileapp" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

I can't open my app:

[image: Image_1]

[image: Image_2]

This is default open of Android.

Please help me!

Thanks!

Comment: It will not work by typing the app's url into a mobile browser, create a html page with your app's deep link as an href, load that page into the browser and tap the link...

Comment: Agree wiht sushi, you should create a html oage for your app. There is link about IOS and android achieve Mobile Deep Linking,you could  refer to it.https://medium.com/@ageitgey/everything-you-need-to-know-about-implementing-ios-and-android-mobile-deep-linking-f4348b265b49